# C++: Variable Not Affected By The Void Function

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, sorting

I've tried to implement a basic quick sort algorithm and I think I've implemented it correctly. However the functions does not affect array at all. What could possibly be the reason? I couldn't figure out what's wrong so I've decided to consult to my fellow programmers in here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int partition(vector<int> A,int low,int high)
{
    int pivot=A[high-1];
    int boundryForLowerArray=low-1;
    for(int i=low;i<high-2;i++)
    {
        if(A[i]<=pivot)
        {
            boundryForLowerArray++;
            swap(A[i],A[boundryForLowerArray]);
        }
    }
    swap(pivot,A[boundryForLowerArray+1]);
    return boundryForLowerArray+1;
}
void quickSort(vector<int>A,int low,int high)
{
    if(low<high)
    {
        int q=partition(A,low,high);
        quickSort(A, low, q-1);
        quickSort(A, q+1, high);
    }
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    vector<int>A,sorted;
    A.push_back(2);
    A.push_back(8);
    A.push_back(7);
    A.push_back(1);
    A.push_back(3);
    A.push_back(5);
    A.push_back(6);
    A.push_back(4);
    quickSort(A, 0, A.size());
    for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++)
        cout<<A[i]<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a complete sample program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing A by value instead of by reference, so `quickSort` is making a copy of A and sorting that. Instead try passing the vector by reference:

```
int partition(vector<int>& A,int low,int high)
```

... and

```
void quickSort(vector<int>& A,int low,int high)
```

Comment: @rolandbishop Just change the two lines he mentions above (ie `vector<int>` to `vector<int>&`), and it works like a charm.

Comment: I guess it does however it made me realize that I've written a quick sort algorithm that doesn't sort lol.

Answer (score 0):

Because you pass the params by value and not by reference. Actually you should have a function with iterators for the start and the end of an array (vec.begin(), vec.end()) as parameter. Additionally your algorithm should accept any kind of iterator. So you should use templates!

```
template<class Iterator>
void quick_sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end) { 
   for(auto iter = begin;iter != end;iter++) 
      *iter; // access to the value of the iterator
```